# How can I redirect a form to the home page?

Tags: 8, forms

I have below code

```
global $base_url;
$form['submit'] = [
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#button_type' => 'primary',
        '#value' => $this->t('Submit'),
        '#attributes' => [
            'onclick' => "window.location='" . $base_url . "'",
        ],
    ];
```

But it's not working. It's not redirecting to home page. How can I redirect a form to the home page upon submission?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's a custom form please include submitForm which is an implementation of FormInterface for processing of submitted data.:

```
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
... 
public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $form_state->setRedirect('<front>'); //This will redirect you to the front page 
}
```